# react router not rendering components at route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My root component is shown below:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Menu />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/'>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/about'>
                    <About />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and then my **Menu** component is shown below:

```
function Menu() {
    return (
        <ul className='menu'>
            <li className='menu-item'>
                <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='menu-item'>
                <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Menu)
```

The problem is that when I click the relevant link, my `About` component does not render but the url shows up in the url bar. I am not sure what's wrong and I have gone through all of the questions related to this topic and none of their suggestions have helped me. I am using `redux` but I do not think that is what is causing the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the `exact` prop should be added to the route that renders the `Home` component:

```
<Router>
    ...
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    ...
</Router>
```

The reason for that is to restrict rendering of the `Home` component to an exact match of `"/"`. Without the `exact` prop, the `Home` component will also be rendered for other partially matched routes (ie `"/about"`, which would be considered a partial match).

Some other suggestions; you might consider assigning the component rendered for a route via the `component` prop on the `Route` component by doing this:

```
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Additionally, you can avoid wrapping the `Menu` component with the `withRouter`.

For a working example, [see this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-gsel9) - hope these pointers help! :)

Answer (score 1):

add `exact`to your rout, like this

```
<Route exact path='/'>
  <Home />
</Route>
<Route exact path='/about'>
  <About />
</Route>
```

Comment: wow I can't believe I didn't try this... do you mind explaining why the router doesn't work without `exact`?

Comment: basically path="/" could be any path, like path="/about", so react takes the first route. so in this case you either have to bring path to home after path to about or put exact param.
p.s: if it worked please choose it as answer and vote up

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Router` logic like this.

```
 <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Menu />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component = {Home}/>
                <Route path='/about' exact component = {About}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
```